# Excel Formula to Pull All Items From a List That Have A Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

I have an Excel row like this:

[image]

```
Test1   Test2   Test3   Test4   Test5   Test6   Test7   Test8   Test9
1000000 100000  2000000 5000    1000000 1000000     100
```

I want to return a columnar result that looks like this:

[image]

```
Test1   1000000
Test2   100000
Test3   2000000
Test4   5000
Test5   1000000
Test6   1000000
Test8   100
```

My data may or may not have ties in it which is giving me an issue with the formula I am using.

I don't care about order at this point, I just need to get a list of items (out of a possible 9) with values and their value.

The two formulas I have written follow. They have both been dragged down 9 rows:

**Item**:`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$26:$I$26,MATCH(SMALL($A$27:$I$27,$F32),$A$27:$I$27,0)),"")`
 
**Value**: `=IFERROR(SMALL($A$27:$I$27,$F32),"")`

And what I get is this:

[image]

I know the ties are causing it to only list the first item in the rank, because of the Match formula.

I also know this is possible and that I've seen something similar on SO before, but cannot find the question nor figure it out myself.

If anyone can provide a formula or link to a similar question I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two formulas:

Limit:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL($A$2:$I$2,ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Then using that for Coverage the Array formula:

```
=IF(L2<>"",INDEX($A$1:$I$1,MATCH(1,($A$2:$I$2=L2)*(COUNTIF($K$1:K1,$A$1:$I$1)=0),0)),"")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: I was hoping you would see this :) and knew you'd answer perfectly if you did! Thanks Scott!